# Preg_replace Only If the Whole Rule Occurs, Preserving Individual Matches Intact

Tags: php

I have a string that contains both individual numbers (can be single digit, can be multiple as well) and numbers with square brackets around them like `[4]`

I am using regular expressions and trying to remove all occurrences of the numbers with the square brackets, leaving regular numbers alone.

E.g, if the string was `32 02 53 [1] [2] [33]`, the result should be `32 02 53`.

The current code I use is:

```
$data = preg_replace('#[(\d+)]#', '', $data);
```

But this replaces/removes all numbers and leaves the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = preg_replace('#\[[0-9]+\]#', '', $data);
```

Because with unescaped brackets it means: a group of one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

[ and ] are reserved symbols - look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Try adding a "\" -> \[ and \]